# How do I explicitly return Unit?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What is the proper way to explicitly return the `Unit` type from a method, using `()` or `Unit`? It appears to me that both work in all cases I've tried myself.

For context, this often occurs if I'm writing a method with side effects and returns `Unit` that calls another method, which also performs side effects but returns some value instead of `Unit`. e.g.

```
def effectAndReturn(): String = {
  val msg = "Hello, SO"
  println(msg)
  msg
}

def doEffect(): Unit = {
  val _ = effectAndReturn()
  () // `Unit` also works here
}
```

From my understanding `()` is the only value of type `Unit` that exists. Returning the token `Unit` in `doEffect()` is referencing the `Unit` companion object; I'm confused how this would return a value as there's not even an `apply` method defined on it. Returning the companion object for a given abstract class's type isn't valid as a return value as far as I know.

Plugging these into a Scala REPL is also interesting

```
scala> val parenUnit = ()
parenUnit: Unit = ()

scala> parenUnit
// Returns blank line

scala> val wordUnit = Unit
wordUnit: Unit.type = object scala.Unit

scala> wordUnit
res1: Unit.type = object scala.Unit

scala> res1
res2: Unit.type = object scala.Unit
```

`()` is simply a `Unit` value, whereas `Unit` gives back a type, which doesn't make sense to me as no other companion objects do this as far as I can tell. My guess is that the compiler handles `Unit` in a particular and unique way compared to any other type, but how exactly?

Comment: You can use `akka.Done` instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So, we have:

- The `Unit` *type*
- The unit value, i.e. `()` which is of type `Unit`
- The `Unit` companion object which causes the confusion. It is **not** of type `Unit`. It is of type `Unit.type` (its own singleton type). However... Scala automatically implicitly converts everything to `Unit` and that's why you can use it where `Unit` type is expected.

TLDR: Use `()`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have two methods in a class called `TestUnit`:

```
class TestUnit {
  def foo(): Unit = 2217
  def bar(): Int = 1478
}
```

Let's look at its bytecode:

```
  // access flags 0x1
  public foo()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 4 L0
    SIPUSH 2217
    POP
    RETURN // returns void
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lunit/TestUnit; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x1
  public bar()I
   L0
    LINENUMBER 5 L0
    SIPUSH 1478
    IRETURN // returns integer because it is declared in method
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lunit/TestUnit; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

My assumption is - the Scala compiler just put `RETURN` instruction (which returns void) in every method where `Unit` is declared as returning type. (you can look listings [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings))

So you can return any type in `doEffect()`. But as **@ghik** said, it's better to use `()`.